# Crop and fill image to fixed dimensions without stretching or extending past the ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView that needs to be a fixed size, say 50x50. I want to fetch an image from the web, have the image fill the area of the imageView entirely, but not show any parts of the image that extend past the 50x50 size. I am targeting API 14 and greater, so `setCropToPadding` is not an option.

Currently my `ImageView` has `ScaleType` CENTER_CROP, but the image extends past the edges of the view.

Is there another way to fill an `ImageView` with an image but not extend past the bounds and not distort the image?

Comment: and why is it a problem with `center_crop` that the image extends past the edges, its not like that is visible

Comment: The image that extends past the edges is visible, in my case at least. Let me double check that the view is the size I think it is...

Comment: My `ImageView` is within an `ActionBar` and I've added padding to make it the size I want. Is having the padding allowing the image to show the parts that are extending? I guess I was incorrect to say the image extended past the ImageView bounds, it was really the ImageView minus padding's bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I had padding set on the ImageView. The definition of CENTER_CROP says it will set the width/height of the image to be at least the width/height (respectively) of the view MINUS padding. This allowed ImageView to return something that filled the ImageView minus padding, but only cropped at the padding.

To fix the issue, I set the padding of the imageView to 0, and set the LayoutParams to have margins with the padding value I really wanted. In API 16 they added setCropToPadding which is really what I wanted, but this solution works for lower versions.